# Javascript Image Placement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

So I am building a puzzle pipe game and wanted each level to have a different background. The background is loaded from an img src only problem the image at he moment doest move with the screen size... I always want it to be centred so you can see the middle of the image.

For example a background that looks perfect on a 13" screen on a 27" looks a total mess... Is there a simple way I can keep the image within the same place? I know I could set up a css rule however was wondering if there was way a way to add it into the js script?

So far my js script looks like this (for one level):

```
var levels = {
level1: {
            level: [[["0","1","0","1"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"]],[["0","0","1","1"],["0","1","1","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"]],[["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","1","1"],["1","1","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"]],[["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","1","1"],["1","0","1","0"],["1","0","1","0"],["1","1","0","0"]]],
            backgroundURL : "http://website.co.uk/client_files/level1.jpg"
        },
```

Thank you

Comment: what about it looks like a mess?  is it duplicating? is it not centered? is the image supposed to grow with a resize or remain a consistent size while remaining centered?

Comment: sorry i should have explained the pipes needs to be generated each time (hence the 0 and 1) my main question is how to get the image resizing while staying centred in js

Answer (score 0):

If you want your game to always be in the middle of the screen, 
follow this article:
https://css-tricks.com/positioning-offset-background-images/

suppose you have a `<div id="game"></div>` as your canvas

set a base css to center the  element background

```
#game{
    background-color: lightgray;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

the javascript code will be very simple
just get the main element and update just the image url

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('#game');

canvas.style.backgroundImage = " url('"+levels.level1.backgroundURL+"')";

// simulate a level change after 3 seconds
setTimeout(function(){
    canvas.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+levels.level2.backgroundURL+"')";
}, 3000);
```

look a running code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/zw7dv9at/2/

Comment: sorry had that as an example updated the js code to how it is in my working script